# Assets owned by a contract

Tags: nft, assets

I know that from a solidity contract, we can receive funds (ethereum) and send funds to a wallet. Essentially, the smart contract owns the Eth that was sent to it.
Similarly, can other assets (such as an NFT)  be owned,  received or sent from a contract to/from a wallet or another contract? If so, how can I do this? Any sample code or other examples would be helpful.
__
Here is some clarification on what I want to be able do:

1. transfer a ERC-721 or ERC-1155 token (NFT) to the contract address, just like I can transfer an NFT from one wallet in Metamask to another wallet.
2. Based on certain conditions, I would like to sell the NFT from the contract
3. Based on  certain conditions , I would like to purchase an NTF via the contract with funds and transfer the NFT to a metamask wallet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? To call a contract you need its address and the contract interface, then it is just calling a function from the interface, e.g. to transfer an ERC-20 token you would do something like `IERC20(address).transfer(recipient, amount)`.

Comment: To clarify, I want to 1) transfer a ERC-721 or ERC-1155 token (NFT)  to the contract address, just like I can transfer an NFT from one wallet in Metamask to another wallet. 2) Based on certain conditions, I would like to sell the NFT from the contract.

Comment: You want an example of a very specific use case. I'd suggest to start by writing a contract that interact with EIP-721 or EIP-1155 tokens. Then write code that trigger under certain conditions. I could write something but 1/ it takes time, 2/ you won't have learn how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I will try myself. I was just wondering if it is even possible for a contract to hold an NFT (not just ETH).